# Heroku db:migrate adding migrations before table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I made a rails 4 app with the default sqllite. But on heroku when I run my first migration I get errors, meanwhile everything works flawlessly locally:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Error:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3709
Migrating to AddIndexToUserName (20131003064019)
==  AddIndexToUserName: migrating =============================================
-- add_index(:users, :name, {:unique=>true})
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "name" does not exist
: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "index_users_on_name" ON "users"  ("name")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "name" does not exist
: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "index_users_on_name" ON "users"  ("name")/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `exec'
/
```

This is my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: poets_app_development
  pool: 5
  username: alain
  password: some_password
```

Comment: Did you follow the rails 4 guide? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Comment: have you verified that this migration AddIndexToUserName (20131003064019) -- is actually listed after the create migration for users?  And also that all your migrations are checked in to git? If you have you might try resetting your db on heroku `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` and then migrate again

Comment: Yes this is right after devise create user (20131002004317), when I type heroku pg:reset DATABASE and do the migrate the error is the same again (sorry for late response)

Comment: and my migrations are added to git, also @agmin I was following that guide

Answer (score 1):

So, if I were to debug this I would do two things.

1. Use the same DB in development as you would in production(best practice and will save time in the long run).
2. Try dropping the DB and re-running the migration locally. I suspect that this will fail as well.

   ```
   rake db:reset
   rake db:migrate
   ```

It seems like your migrations might be out of order or referencing something that is not yet in the database. This should throw an error locally as well.

Comment: Can you give me the error that it throws locally? Does it throw an error locally?